# Android: ActionBar with fixed bottom layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make an app which the main screen is an tabbed interface, and bellow the tab control there is a fixed strip of controls.

My first try, was adding into my XML another linear layout bellow the android.support.v4.view.ViewPager and setting `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);` . This hides the layout at the bottom.

When I try `NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD` I see the layout at the bottom, but the app crashes when I switch tabs.

I found something similar in Appolo Music, however I did not understand were the player strip is defined (full code is here: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Apollo)

[image: Appolo Music - usually found on Cyanogenmod]

EDIT:
I found using the Hierarchy viewer that the extra layout gets deleted on runtime. This is interesting.